# Prawn: Is there a way for vertical alignment of all content in a box?

Tags: ruby, alignment, prawn, bounding-box, valign

I'm trying to position some content vertically centered in a bounding_box. With a single text this is no problem:

```
bounding_box([0, bounds.top], :width => pdf.bounds.right, :height => pdf.bounds.top) do
  text "vertically aligned in the surrounding box", :valign => :center
end
```

But what can I do if a have multiple elements in my bounding box:

```
bounding_box([0, bounds.top], :width => pdf.bounds.right, :height => pdf.bounds.top) do
  text "vertically aligned in the surrounding box", :valign => :center
  text "vertically aligned in the surrounding box", :valign => :center
end
```

That won't work, the text is overlaid when you try this...

I'm looking for a way to group the whole content of the bounding_box and then align that whole group vertically. Is there any way to do this with prawn??

Thanks a lot for your help!
Chris

Answer (score 7):

If you only have text lines, you can still use `formatted_text` with `\n` in your text :

```
formatted_text [
    { text: "#{line1}\n" },
    { text: "#{line2}" }
  ],
  valign: :center,
  leading: 6
```

I'm still trying to figure out how to handle a picture/legend group, since even tables don't seem to do the trick.